# How to convert each value of a series to a list, then combine them to a list?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, series, gensim

for example, I have a df like this:

```
       A
0   I like this
1   I like that
```

which was created by:

```
df = DataFrame({'A':['I like this','I like that']})
```

Now for df['A'], I want to convert this series to a list of lists, like this:

```
[['I like this'],['I like that']]
```

I searched about this but I only got suggestions like tolist(), which converts a series to a list, not what I look for

```
['I like this', 'I like that']
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!
I use such df for gensim use.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `apply` the `list` operation on each row individually as well.

```py
df.apply(list, axis=1).tolist()
```

If you just want this `apply` on a few columns in your DF, simply slice into the DF using:

```py
df[['A']].apply(list, axis=1).tolist()
```

Output

```py
[['I like this'], ['I like that']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try list comprehension, to convert a list into a list of lists

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['I like this','I like that']})
my_list = list(df['A'])
[[i] for i in my_list]
#Output: [['I like this'], ['I like that']]
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative:

```
new_list =list(map(lambda x:[x], list(df.A.values)))
#[['I like this'], ['I like that']]
```